# hibernate no result when column value is null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a table with multiple pk and some column can have a null value

When all columns have data I got from hibernate a full resultset.

The problem came when when one or more column have a null value, then hibernate didn't load the data.

Here is the table schema

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `configuration_changed` (
`table_name` TEXT(30) NOT NULL,
`column_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`idbox` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`pk` TEXT NOT NULL,
`old_value` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`new_value` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`type` ENUM('NEW','DELETE','CHANGE') NULL,
INDEX `FK_conf_changed_idbox_idx` (`idbox` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `FK_conf_changed_idbox`
FOREIGN KEY (`idbox`)
REFERENCES `box` (`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
```

this is the code of my model :

```
 @Entity
 @IdClass(ConfigurationChanged.class)
 @Table(name="configuration_changed")
 @NamedQuery(name="ConfigurationChanged.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM ConfigurationChanged c")
public class ConfigurationChanged implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="column_name", length=45)
private String columnName;

@Id
@Column(nullable=false)
private Timestamp date;

@Column(name="new_value", length=45, nullable=true)
private String newValue;

@Column(name="old_value", length=45, nullable=true)
private String oldValue;

@Id
@Lob
@Column(nullable=false)
private String pk;

@Id
@Lob
@Column(name="table_name", nullable=false)
private String tableName;

@Column(length=1)
private String type;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Box
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idbox", nullable=false)
private Box box;

// getters and setters ...
```

When I put the query that hibernate make on a mysql shell I didn't found any problem and got the result

What i am missing ?

Thanks for your help (and sorry for my english)

I found the problem but not the root cause

The problem came from the hashCode method that I override

```
    @Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;

    result = prime * result + ((columnName == null) ? 0 : columnName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((date == null) ? 0 : date.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((pk == null) ? 0 : pk.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((tableName == null) ? 0 : tableName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((box == null || box.getId() == null) ? 0 : (int) (box.getId() ^ (box.getId() >>> 32)));
    result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((newValue == null) ? 0 : newValue.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((oldValue == null) ? 0 : oldValue.hashCode());


    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you use criteria to match some fields which comes on a request from a page?

Comment: @drgPP  No I am calling findAll method

Comment: A TEXT column, mapped as a CLOB, as part of a primary key? Seriously? This is insane. Fix your schema and use a single-column, auto-generated, purely technical primary key.

Comment: @ShalomOhayon did you override equals method ?